# GIT Pull & Clone times out

Tags: git, firewall

I've recently set up a small turnkeylinux revision control VM (which has about 256MB RAM), and am attempting to clone one of the repositories I pushed up to it. It is very fast to push to (via ssh) but is extremely slow to pull from.

Here's what I get if I leave it till SSH times out:

```
$ git pull
andrewm@1.2.3.4's password:
remote: Counting objects: 403, done.
Read from remote host 1.2.3.4: The connection was aborted
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
```

I attempted the clone like so:

```
> mkdir myProj
> cd myProj
> git init
> git remote add origin git+ssh://andrewm@1.2.3.4/srv/repos/git/myProj
> git pull
```

When I issue the pull command it reaches 50% almost instantly, and then halts. It slowly creeps forward a few more percent (one attempt reached 66%) and then eventually dies if left long enough.

This repo is tiny with only a handful of revisions so far. My main repo is much bigger and will also be unusable unless this issue is identified.

Any ideas what could be causing the sudden slowdown?

#### Update

I opened the firewall and found that the git-daemon protocol also timed out, so it's not related to SSH. Changed the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

a/ Check your ssh connection from your new local server
(try a direct ssh to check you can connect to the remote, then a ssh-based operation: `sftp` or `scp`)

b/ what a `git clone` (instead of `git init` + `git remote add` + `git pull`) gives you?

```
 git clone ssh://user@server:project.git
 git clone ssh://andrewm@1.2.3.4/srv/repos/git/myProj
```

(and what about using directly the [ssh protocol](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html) in the git remote address?)

c/ What a *second* `git pull` displays? Does it pick up where it left? (like [`git svn rebase` does](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-03/msg03203.html))

Comment: I can SSH to the machine, and can scp to it OK. Git clone gives same behaviour as init + remote pull. haven't yet tried the re-pull. will get back to you